# Is it possible to rearrange this equation to make $a$ the subject?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The equation that I would like to rearrange in order that $a$ is the subject is as follows:

$a^t(1-a)-a=m(1-a^2)$

All suggestions appreciated.

(Edit: clarification. By "making $a$ the subject", I mean getting $a$ on one side and having the other side have no $a$).

Comment: What do you mean by being "the subject"? Do you mean getting $a$ on one side and having the other side have no $a$?

Comment: That's what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: Is $t$ an integer? Is there are limit on the values $t$ can take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a^t(1-a)-a=m(1-a^2)$

$\frac{a^t(1-a)-a}{(1-a^2)}=m$

$\frac{a^t}{(1+a)} - \frac{a}{(1-a^2)}=m$

Terms containing $a$ are complex.